# WPF listboxitem IsSelected binding does not work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am binding **ItemsSource** of a lisbox control to **`ObservableCollection<Course>`**. **Course** class has a property **IsSelected**. The IsSelected property of Course is bound to IsSelected of ListBoxItem as shown below:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}" SelectionMode="Extended"
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>


 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"  x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CourseTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedCourseTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

There is a button the screen which executes a command when clicked. The command calls a method that iterates over the List and sets the IsSelected to true / false. When IsSelected is set to true on Course object the "SelectedCourseTemplate" gets applied but when it is set to false "CourseTemplate" does not get applied.

Also since the listbox is in "Extended" selection mode, I want to be able to set the IsSelected property on the corresponding Course object when user selects multiple items in the list.

UPDATE **
Course class is as below

```
public class Course : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedNotification("IsSelected");
            }
        }

 private void RaisePropertyChangedNotification(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CourseTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <!-- Bunch of column definitions here -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <!-- Textbox, StackPanel etc set in each of the columns here -->

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks

Comment: post your *Data Item* (the `Course` class).

Comment: @HighCore updated question with Course class

Comment: The error must be in the definition of the `ContainerStyle`. If you're not `{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}` somewhere within that template, then the modification of the `ContentTemplate` will have no effect. can you post that too?

Comment: @HighCore Update the question with template. Nowhere in the CourseTemplate am i doing any sort of {TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Are you using that template as the `ControlTemplate` for the `ListBoxItem` or as the `ContentTemplate`? these are 2 different things, you should be doing the latter.

Comment: @HighCore I am using it as a ContentTemplate.

Comment: Could it be that you used a Trigger instead of a DataTrigger?

Comment: @JoelLucsy I tried DataTrigger too and it didnt work